# Match the IDs one file with the other and place it in the same order Ruby

Tags: ruby

```
def matchid (line, lineline)
  m = /x:Key="(\S+)"/.match(line)
  n = /x:Key="(\S+)"/.match(lineline)
  if m == n
    return true
  else
    return false
  end
end

def matchcomment(line, lineline)
  m = /<!-- (.+) -->/.match(line)
  n = /<!-- (.+) -->/.match(lineline)
  if m == n
    return true
  else
    return false
  end
end

def matchspace(line, lineline)
  m = /(\s+)/.match(line)
  n = /(\s+)/.match(lineline)
  if m == n
    return true
  else
    return false
  end
end

matchline = 1

f = File.open('chi.xaml' , 'r')
file = File.open('eng.xaml' , 'r') 
newFile = File.open('chinew.xaml' , 'w')

f.each_line do |line|
  if matchline == 1
    lineline = file.gets
  else
    lineline = lineline
  end
  if matchid(line, lineline) == true
    newFile.puts(line)
    matchline = 1
  elsif matchcomment(line, lineline) == true
    newFile.puts(line)
    matchline = 1
  elsif matchspace(line, lineline) == true
    newFile.puts(line)
    matchline = 1
  else
    matchline = 0
  end
end
```

Basically, I want to compare 2 files which have the same IDs but 1 of it has it's order messed up.
I want to arrange the file to match the order of the other, I tried using the codes above but can't seem to get the right output.

Lines in file 1:

```
    <!-- VitalSignsView String -->
          <sys:String x:Key="IDS_STRING_FSM_VITAL_SIGN_CPU">CPU</sys:String>
          <sys:String x:Key="IDS_STRING_FSM_VITAL_SIGN_RAM">RAM</sys:String>
          <sys:String x:Key="IDS_STRING_FSM_VITAL_SIGN_MB">MB</sys:String>
          <sys:String x:Key="IDS_STRING_FSM_VITAL_SIGN_OPEN_BRACKET">(</sys:String>
          <sys:String x:Key="IDS_STRING_FSM_VITAL_SIGN_CLOSE_BRACKET">b)</sys:String>
          <!-- SetupButtonBarView -->
          <sys:String x:Key="IDS_BUTTONBAR_FSM_SETUP_CONFIG_OVERVIEW">Config Overview</sys:String>
          <sys:String x:Key="IDS_BUTTONBAR_FSM_SETUP_INSTRUMENT">Instrument Setup</sys:String>
          <sys:String x:Key="IDS_BUTTONBAR_FSM_SETUP_USER_PREFERENCE">User Preference</sys:String>
          <sys:String x:Key="IDS_BUTTONBAR_FSM_SETUP_HW_SW_INFO">HW/SW Info</sys:String>
          <sys:String x:Key="IDS_BUTTONBAR_FSM_SETUP_INSTALLED_OPTION">Installed Options</sys:String>
          <sys:String x:Key="IDS_BUTTONBAR_FSM_SETUP_EXIT">Exit</sys:String>
```

Lines in file 2:

```
<!-- SetupButtonBarView -->
      <sys:String x:Key="IDS_BUTTONBAR_FSM_SETUP_CONFIG_OVERVIEW">Config Overview</sys:String>
      <sys:String x:Key="IDS_BUTTONBAR_FSM_SETUP_INSTRUMENT">仪器设置</sys:String>
      <sys:String x:Key="IDS_BUTTONBAR_FSM_SETUP_USER_PREFERENCE">用户喜好设置</sys:String>
      <sys:String x:Key="IDS_BUTTONBAR_FSM_SETUP_HW_SW_INFO">硬件/软件信息</sys:String>
      <sys:String x:Key="IDS_BUTTONBAR_FSM_SETUP_INSTALLED_OPTION">已装选件</sys:String>
      <sys:String x:Key="IDS_BUTTONBAR_FSM_SETUP_EXIT">退出</sys:String>
      <!-- VitalSignsView -->
      <sys:String x:Key="IDS_STRING_FSM_VITAL_SIGN_CPU">CPU</sys:String>
      <sys:String x:Key="IDS_STRING_FSM_VITAL_SIGN_RAM">RAM</sys:String>
      <sys:String x:Key="IDS_STRING_FSM_VITAL_SIGN_MB">MB</sys:String>
      <sys:String x:Key="IDS_STRING_FSM_VITAL_SIGN_OPEN_BRACKET">(</sys:String>
      <sys:String x:Key="IDS_STRING_FSM_VITAL_SIGN_CLOSE_BRACKET">b)</sys:String>
```

Output wanted:

```
<!-- VitalSignsView -->
      <sys:String x:Key="IDS_STRING_FSM_VITAL_SIGN_CPU">CPU</sys:String>
      <sys:String x:Key="IDS_STRING_FSM_VITAL_SIGN_RAM">RAM</sys:String>
      <sys:String x:Key="IDS_STRING_FSM_VITAL_SIGN_MB">MB</sys:String>
      <sys:String x:Key="IDS_STRING_FSM_VITAL_SIGN_OPEN_BRACKET">(</sys:String>
      <sys:String x:Key="IDS_STRING_FSM_VITAL_SIGN_CLOSE_BRACKET">b)</sys:String>
      <!-- SetupButtonBarView -->
      <sys:String x:Key="IDS_BUTTONBAR_FSM_SETUP_CONFIG_OVERVIEW">Config Overview</sys:String>
      <sys:String x:Key="IDS_BUTTONBAR_FSM_SETUP_INSTRUMENT">仪器设置</sys:String>
      <sys:String x:Key="IDS_BUTTONBAR_FSM_SETUP_USER_PREFERENCE">用户喜好设置</sys:String>
      <sys:String x:Key="IDS_BUTTONBAR_FSM_SETUP_HW_SW_INFO">硬件/软件信息</sys:String>
      <sys:String x:Key="IDS_BUTTONBAR_FSM_SETUP_INSTALLED_OPTION">已装选件</sys:String>
      <sys:String x:Key="IDS_BUTTONBAR_FSM_SETUP_EXIT">退出</sys:String>
```

Comment: Have you considered using an xml parser, such as nokogiri, instead of string matching? That would allow you to iterate one file, and use #css to search for the same id in the other.

Comment: I have problem installing some of the ruby tools including nokogiri that's why i use string matching and regex @BrianMurphy-Dye

Comment: Cool, then perhaps this: (1) parse the second file into a hash, with the id as the hash key and the inner text as the value, and then (2) iterate over the lines in the first file, and build the new file with this id and hash[id].

Comment: I'll try and repost the new codes later @BrianMurphy-Dye

Answer (score 1):

```
unordered_file = File.read('unordered_file')
unordered_lines = unordered_file.each_line.reduce(Set.new) {|set, line| set << line}
ordered_file = File.read('ordered_file')
File.open('out', 'w') do |f|
  ordered_file.each_line {|line| f.puts(line) if unordered_lines.contains?(line)}
end
```

Should work assuming you have no duplicate lines in `ordered_file`

Comment: Is there an alternative for the Set command? i get undefined local variable Set when running. I think it is because I am running ruby on windows

Comment: You could use a Hash and just use the values

Answer (score 1):

Josh, great solution except it appears he needs to match the lines against just the keys instead of the whole line, as the inner text differs sometimes. Replacing the text inside the File.open loop with something like this might work:

```
ordered_file.each_line do |line|
    m = /x:Key="(\S+)"/.match(line)
    f.puts(line) if m and unordered_lines.contains?(m[1])
end
```

Comment: I can't use the contains command, I think it's because I am running ruby on windows. I tried using .include but i doesn't work

Comment: So sorry, this should be unordered_lines.include?(m[1])